# Get only images

Tags: box-api

Is there any way to get only images (only audio or video) using box-api.

I tried to use search api and If-Match condition but didnt find any way to do this.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your audio/video files have extensions?  The Search API should work in this case.  You can search for multiple extensions at one time if you put a space between them:

`GET /2.0/search?query=jpg%20mp4%20png`

Comment: I have to get all images without considering file extensions. Is it possible to search based on MIME type like images/*

Comment: The `File` object doesn't currently support mime/content types. :\

Comment: Just curious -- how is it that your files are being upload without extensions?  Box has no way to know what they are -- preview doesn't work, etc.

Comment: I never said files are uploaded without file extension. Its just that I dont want to restrict search to only specific type of images.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: If user has uploaded an image file with extension not included in my search then in this case, image will not appear in my app image gallery. Thats the reason I want to avoid extension based search.

Anyway, thank you for your effort John. Plz update this post just in case u got to know any soln..